# How to make Aptana (Eclipse) not follow symbolic links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, aptana

In Aptana Studio 2.0 (which is actually Eclipse 3.5) I have a Rails project X that includes a symbolic link to a folder Y outside the project folder. Folder Y is big. It contains a lot of files and folders. Building the project and refresing the workspace takes a lot of time. Therefore I do not like Eclipse to take the contents of folder Y into account when building project X and when determining resources with the Open Resource command.

I am looking for a way to exclude the symbolic link from the build path. I tried excluding it from the Ruby Load Path of the project, but Aptana still builds the files in the excluded folder.

So my questions are:

1. Does excluding folders from the build path actually work in Aptana?
2. Is this an Aptana issue or an Eclipse issue?
3. Is there a way to make Eclipse/Aptana not follow symbolic links?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd be interested in this too - aptana is crashing (eventually running out of memory) when I have a symbolic link that points to a directory two levels up.

Comment: ofc is an Eclipse issue, it happens in CDT plugin too on `Kepler Service Release 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using Aptana Studio 3 for this issue for two reasons:

1) There were some issues with the build process in RadRails 2.X where large directories of files are concerned. This has been corrected.

2) You can now exclude certain directories from the indexing process by choosing "Indexing > Exclude From Index"

This won't necessarily remove the files from the open resource command, but it should solve the long indexing/out of memory errors.

Comment: Edit: with the latest Eclipse, go to Project Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters and add a filter to exclude symbolic links